# PHP - Multiselect require field if option is selected

Tags: php, multi-select, required

This is part of a form that is sent via e-mail. When you select the option state the textfield state is required, if you don't it isn't, same for county and zip code.
What I want is the php to validate this so I can send the e-mail but so far I haven't been able to accomplish it.

Here is the HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="geographic" id="geographic">
    <option value="state">State</option>
    <option value="county">County</option>
    <option value="zip">Zip Code</option>
</select>
<label for="state">What state?</label>
<input id="state" name="state" type="text">
<label for="county">What County?</label>
<input id="county" name="county" type="text">
<label for="zipcode">What is the Zip Code? *</label>
<input id="zipcode" name="zipcode" type="text">
```

Comment: You don't need to do this validation on the server. Why not use JavaScript instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Javascript` which allows the validation on the front end and doesn't require a page load, something like the following should work for you:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SelectValidator() {
  // Get the select object
  var index = document.getElementById("geographic").selectedIndex;
  var select = document.getElementById("geographic").options;

  // Get our input elements
  var county = document.getElementById('county');
  var state = document.getElementById('state');
  var zipcode = document.getElementById('zipcode');

  if (select[index].value === "county") {
    if (county.value === null || county.value === "") {
      alert("Please complete the County field");
    } else {
      alert("You could simply put a return statement here.");
    }
  } else if (select[index].value === "state") {
    if (state.value === null || state.value === "") {
      alert("Please complete the state field");
    } else {
      alert("You could simply put a return statement here.");
    }
  } else if (select[index].value === "zip") {
    if (zipcode.value === null || zipcode.value === "") {
      alert("Please complete the Zip Code field");
    } else {
      alert("You could simply put a return statement here.");
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
```

And your form:

```
<form>
<select multiple="multiple" name="geographic" id="geographic">
    <option value="state">State</option>
    <option value="county">County</option>
    <option value="zip">Zip Code</option>
</select>

<label for="state">What state?</label>
<input id="state" name="state" type="text">

<label for="county">What County?</label>
<input id="county" name="county" type="text">

<label for="zipcode">What is the Zip Code? *</label>
<input id="zipcode" name="zipcode" type="text">


<button type="button" onclick="SelectValidator()">Display index</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

first of you need to wrap your code in a form but you probably did that already? if not you should take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

the php file where the form is posted to receives it with $_POST, in the case of geographicit is $_POST['geographic'], same goes for state. Now you know how  to access that value, you can validate it.

so

```
if($_POST['geographic'] == 'state'){

     if(empty($_POST['state'])){
          echo 'state is required';
     }else{
          echo 'state is given, proceed';
     }

}
```

Comment: [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: Click on the link in my first comment. Read the page to which it points.